# Consuming Rest service with SSL certificate in C#

Tags: c#, rest, ssl, certificate, httprequest

I am trying to consume a rest service to read Active MQ messages in C#. The service has a SSL certificate with no password. I can successfully get the response when I use the service url in browser (chrome, restlet client) but not in postman. I had added the certificate to Chrome before accessing the url.

This is a HTTPS service.

I have to call the service with the SSL cert along with my http request. I have tried WebRequestHandler, HttpWebRequest, HttpClient with no luck.

When I do that, I received the following error.

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

```
string url =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveMQDev"].ToString();
string certFileName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SSLCertPath"].ToString();

// create HTTP web request with proper content type
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF8";
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certFileName);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
WebResponse response;


using (new ServerCertificateValidationScope(request, delegate { return true; }))
{
    // call the web service and get response
    response = request.GetResponse();   
}

if (response != null)
{
    //handle the response
}
```

this suppresses the exception but I get

> RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

error in the callback(sender, certificate, chain, errors).

When I dont have the call to suppress the SSL error, I get a

> 401 unauthorized response from the server.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: does the certificate have the right public key?. Can you verify via the thumbprint of the certificate that you use with the ones that you target against.

Comment: Yes, the certificate I use in my code and the one I have installed on chrome are the same. The thumbprints match.

Comment: are you using a local development certificate for the rest service

Comment: The certificate was given to us by the people who exposed the rest service. Not sure what is missing.

Comment: In case this is a self signed certificate, don't bother validation. Set true in the certificate validation callback

Comment: When I dont validate and just supress the SSL error, I get the Unauthorized 401 response.

Comment: oops, seems you have no authorization headers set in the request, don't you need one?

Comment: So we went back to the team that gave us the cert and it was faulty! We got a cert with password and its a pfx file now. We are directly accessing the queue now attaching the cert in the request. This seems to have resolved the issue with getting to the queue and accessing the messages in it. The only problem we have now is the messages are not dequeuing but i guess thats the AMQ team's headache. If anyone requires the code to access the AMQ directly using the NMS api, please send me a message. I can send a sample. Thanks all for your help. Really appreciate it.!

Comment: One small concern is that, as you are the consumer, you should be using the cer ( public key certificate) instead of the pfx. Can you make sure this is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we went back to the team that gave us the cert and it was faulty! We got a cert with password and its a pfx file now. We are directly accessing the queue now attaching the cert in the request. This seems to have resolved the issue with getting to the queue and accessing the messages in it. The only problem we have now is the messages are not dequeuing but i guess thats the AMQ team's headache. If anyone requires the code to access the AMQ directly using the NMS api, please send me a message. I can send a sample. Thanks all for your help. Really appreciate it.!

Comment: Nice that you sorted out the certificate issue. You can share the code snippets here or through the git gists or via GitHub repository.